# How to remove LayerName.FieldName join format in model builder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder, attribute-joins

[image: Model]

I am running a join in model builder based on a calculated field in a geodatabase table and a created layer.  After the join I am selecting features and copying selection to a new Shapefile.

My issue is that during the join the resulting joined layer has all field named using the LayerName.FieldName naming convention.  I have tried both checking and unchecking the environment setting of "Maintain Fully Qualified Field Names," however, neither are working.  Only way I can seem to fix it is to manually delete and rename the fields during the copy features process.

Wondering is there a specific modelbuilder setting/tool/process I can use to only keep actual field names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool Copy Features honours the qualified field names environment setting. So Use that tool to make a copy of the dataset with the join and work with that.

Comment: Hornbydd, thank you very much, using the copy features tool right after my join worked!  Thanks